# Can I use Guava's ComparisonChain to handle null fields in a special way?

Tags: java, guava, comparator, comparisonchain

I have a ComplexObject with multiple fields and I want to say this:

- if field `x` exists on both, move on to the next `compare` in the comparison chain.
- if both are null, move on to the next `compare` in the comparison chain.
- if one is null and the other is not, put nulls last

I'm not sure how to do this, because as far as I can tell

```
.compare(c1.getX(), c2.getX(), Ordering.arbitrary().nullsLast())
```

will

1. consider the objects to be equal if they both exist and are equal
2. consider the objects to be equal if they're both null.

Is there a way I can use Guava's `ComparisonChain` or `Ordering` class to achieve what I want?  Or is there a better way to think about solving this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you only care about the null-ness or not of each field?

Comment: @EricJablow yes.  But to be more specific, I care about that first, then I will care about other things.  EG: for the next `.compare` I might compare based off of `x`'s `name` field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your answer to my comment, just do a boolean comparison.

```
.compare(c1.getX() == null, c2.getX() == null)
```

And given your revised reply, if your class has a method

```
public XType getX() {...}
```

then consider making `XType` implement `Comparable<XType>` or providing a `Comparator<XType>`.

Comment: The simple compare method for booleans is deprecated in favor of more explicitly named methods now because it's ambiguous and could lead to confusion.  If you want nulls last as stated in the question, you'd want to use compareFalseFirst(c1.getX() == null, c2.getX() == null) or compareTrueFirst(c1.getX() != null, c2.getX() != null)